# CentOS Vs Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, linux, windows-server-2008, centos

Apologies if the question appears ambiguous, I have little experience in this area and was after some informed opinions.

I am deploying a test scenario of a server/client network and need to make some choices for Server.
The client will be a Windows system as it meets the requirements for the client, the server choice has more room for selection.
From my experience with Linux in general and the appealing nature of open source for low cost, security etc and the availability and performance of database and web server programs I have been considering CentOS as a server choice.

How well does this operate with Windows clients?
Am I being too selective and creating unnecessary complication by setting out not to use a Windows Server OS?

Comment: Serverfault is the best place to ask ths quesion. I have voted to close and this will be moved to Serverfault soon. :-)

Comment: oops Just realised I ran out of votes to close.

Comment: ah, I had a quick scout around for server questions and found a few. Didn't even know ServerFault existed! I will post across there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, very ambiguous!

Essentially, your client / server network will be dependent on one thing - clients are Windows, do you want to authenticate using Active Directory? Yes? Then you'll need Windows servers too.

It really depends on what your test scenario is aimed at testing and without significantly more detailed information as to what your end goal is, we'll be at a loss to help you.

This question would actually be better placed on the Server Fault site, unless your ultimate goal is an environment in which to test application development.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will carry this on over on ServerFault if you had any more to add. I will expand the question a bit more based on your comment.